# Is it possible to have a CSV file inside a bootstrap model?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, csv

I've been looking at this one for a while, but I haven't been able to find a right solution. I am using a bootstrap modal to (hopefully) show a CSV file from a directory. I'm using PHP, HTML, and CSS. The objective is to have an `<a>` tag that displays a modal populated with an uneditable CSV screenshot from a directory.

Where the `<img>` is, is where I would like to call the directory to show the CSV file.

Bootstrap:

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="CSVModal" tabindex="1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3>CSV File Preview</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <img id="ctl00_XXX" src="Images/XXX.png" style="border: 0; float: left; margin-right: 15px" />
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Directory:

D:\Upload\Test.csv

---

1. Is this possible with the languages I have chosen?
2. Are there extensions for other languages that I could use to make this more doable?

Comment: You can open the CSV file via AJAX and parse the data into a table, no real PHP required there.  Generating an image of the CSV output is a larger challenge though.

Answer (score 0):

You can feed the contents of the csv into something like papa parse, and present the data in a table inside the div in your popup.

Please see the demo https://www.papaparse.com/demo and look at the local files implementation.